# Why do underpants, knickers have to go with the ‘s’?

Tags: plural-forms

I’ve learned that pants, jeans, shoes, glass are always in plural form because they consist of 2 parts. For example, jeans and pants have 2 pant legs. So why are underpants and knickers always in plural form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outer or otherwise, nether garments are plural. Breeches, pants, trousers, knickers, shorts, drawers, tights, even if they don't extend appreciably down the legs. They accommodate (for most people) two buttocks, if not two legs. Also, knickers often are two-legged.

[image]

Comment: Quite true, although there is a bizarre habit I've noticed in fashion and retail clothing to refer to them in the singular. I have frequently heard both "a trouser", "a jean" and "a pant" used by retail staff and shows like "What Not to Wear".

Comment: Took me a while to find an example, but Stephen Fry of course managed [to notice the peculiar use](https://books.google.ca/books?id=cEVDDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT65&dq=%22a+trouser%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw4vilnKrhAhVrx1kKHa4qB-4Q6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22a%20trouser%22&f=false) (and make fun of it) in the hands of overly obsequious  salespeople.

Comment: When I started at Alleyn's School in 1963 at age 11, the uniform was a plain grey suit. The under 13s had to wear shorts instead of long trousers, and the outfit was called a "knicker suit" in the school's dress regulations.

Comment: I wonder if this stems from an ancient and lost time before sewing when pants would have been more like a pair of chaps - something connected manually at the top rather than pre-sewn for modern convenience.  If at all true, a "pant" would be like a "chap" in that there's one for each leg.  This might explain the modern tradition of plurality.

Comment: Bizarrely enough, men's hose certainly were [not originally joined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codpiece#History), giving rise (no pun intended) to the need for codpieces. But hose were always hose, not hoses, which just goes to show you just can't win.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That would be because it was a suit with [*knickerbockers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knickerbockers_(clothing)) rather than trousers.

Comment: @fred2: In that case, *hose* was a mass noun.

Comment: @JBH That is the explanation for *trousers*, *breeches*, etc always being plural that I found in several sources. Not that it was before sewing, just that the way clothes were worn made it make more sense for the two legs to be separate.

Comment: SamBC - knickerbockers, (your link confirms), are baggy-kneed trousers like golfers wear. The school uniform shorts I wore ended above the knee.

Comment: To respond to the answer itself, why is *skirt* singular, then? It also accommodates two legs. You will find the plural *skirts* in older writing, but I understand that that is because people would never wear just one - you wore several, one over the other.

Comment: A milksop boy hides behind his mothers' skirts, I know, but a skirt, unlike culottes, is not divided.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: the usage ended up wider than that, as one often finds with clothes. Basically, it ended up being a term for reasonably smart short trousers. Regardless, it is certainly the origin of the term [*knickers*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/knickers).

Comment: @SamBC .. yes, it was. Eg. "My hose, my hose, my kingdom for some hose".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yet your answer says this applies "even if they don't appear split or divided"

Comment: There's also the phrase "trouser suit" for a woman's suit, fwiw.

Comment: SamBC - It doesn't any more. The genial Head of the Lower School at Alleyn's, DHB "Butch" Pritchard (a lovely man), told my mother that the rule could be relaxed if a boy was "portly", and it transpired that this also applied if he got hairy legs early.

Comment: Of course, the reason that smaller boys wore short trousers was, AIUI, to do with thrift - you could have one pair for a very long time, if you rolled up and you repaired tears. The shape of proper knickerbockers helped with that as well. Those reasons applied to older boys as well, of course, but the idea of the mark of some semblance of adulthood became important, and then the age when boys switched to long trousers kept creeping down...

Answer (score 2):

Because they are all terms that derive from words that are plural for the same reason as *trousers*, *pants*, etc.<sup>1</sup>

Underpants go *under* your *pants*. Knickers get their name from the actually quite different garment *knickerbockers*. Shorts are *short trousers/pants*. Boxers are *boxer shorts*. Trunks were originally a sort of short *breeches*, with legs. And so on.

Also, most of these garments used to actually have legs, albeit not always full length. Underwear almost as brief as possible (and that's where we get *briefs*, which probably comes from *brief underpants* or something) is quite a modern thing.

---

<sup>1</sup>: The generally accepted reason for this is that two-legged garments weren't originally single garments, but pairs like stockings, that didn't join at the groin. I don't know how solid the evidence for that explanation is.

Comment: You really have to go back a pretty long way before you get two-piece pants. [Ötzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96tzi) wore them, but that was 5000 years ago. In Roman times, even the German tribes wore one-piece pants. Could the plurality of pants have lasted for thousands of years and who knows how many different languages? Possibly.

Comment: @PeterShor: For a fair amount of history in Europe, the crotch-covering garment was separate from the leg-covering garments, which came in two pieces - one for each leg. One-piece garments that we would recognise as trousers existed before that, but were in various times and places only peasant or workman's garments.